# Быстрый по объекту JS

Tags: javascript

Как получить необходимые значения без миллиона вложенных `for (key in data) {}`

```js
var boards = {
  'b1': {
    'title': 'Healthy life',
    'id': '1',
    'lists': [{
        "title": "Todo",
        "id": '1-1',
        "tasks": [{
            "title": "Go Hiking",
            "id": "1-1-1",
            "description": "Take Skutull on his first hike. Maybe Mt. Sonitas?",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          },
          {
            "title": "Make reservation at The Kitchen",
            "id": "1-1-2",
            "description": "Craving a salmon salad sandwich...",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          },
          {
            "title": "Finish Trello app",
            "id": "1-1-3",
            "description": "Get my trello clone up on github and make a screencast for README and website.",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          },
          {
            "title": "Build wine rack",
            "id": "1-1-4",
            "description": "Need to go to Home Depot to get more wood and screws.",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          },
          {
            "title": "Take dog on a walk",
            "id": "1-1-5",
            "description": "",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          }
        ],
        "addTask": false,
      },
      {
        "title": "Doing",
        "id": '1-2',
        "tasks": [{
          "title": "Pay taxes :(",
          "id": "1-2-1",
          "description": "",
          "date": "12.12.2018",
        }, ],
        "addTask": false,
      },
      {
        "title": "Done",
        "id": '1-3',
        "tasks": [{
            "title": "Watch new GOT episode",
            "id": "1-3-1",
            "description": "I swear if Tyrion and John Snow die I will stop watching the show.",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          },
          {
            "title": "Buy toothpaste",
            "id": "1-3-2",
            "description": "",
            "date": "12.12.2018",
          }
        ],
        "addTask": false,
      },
    ],
  },
  'b2': {
    'title': 'Sport',
    'id': '2',
    'lists': [],
  },
  'b3': {
    'title': 'Reading books',
    'id': '3',
    'lists': [],
  },
  'b4': {
    'title': 'VueJS',
    'id': '4',
    'lists': [],
  },
  'b5': {
    'title': 'Javascript',
    'id': '5',
    'lists': [],
  },
  'b6': {
    'title': 'PHP',
    'id': '6',
    'lists': [],
  },
}
```

Знаю значение вложенного `"id"` - например `"1-1-1"`. Как можно получить значения которые возле нужного `"id"` ?

В этом случае это `"title": "Go Hiking"`, `"description": "Take Skutull on his first hike. Maybe Mt. Sonitas?"`, `"date": "12.12.2018"`

P.S. `id` `родителей` я тоже знаю, в этом случае это `1-1` и `1` , но у меня всё равно получается штук 7 вложенных циклов...
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если бы у вас были массивы объектов, то можно было бы выпрямить `_.flattenDeep` в 1-н массив, и найти по id - нужный массив.

а так вариант решения for и 2-а find -> https://jsfiddle.net/0daLv7b7/

```
var k_1 = '1';
var k_2 = '1-1';
var k_3 = '1-1-1';
var elem;
for (var i in boards){
    if (boards[i].id != k_1) continue;
    var secondParent = boards[i].lists.find(function(o){
        return o.id == k_2;
    })
    elem = secondParent.tasks.find(function(o){
        return o.id == k_3;
    })
}
alert(elem.title)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно :)

Answer (score 2):

Вижу два решения

### 1. Полным перебором через циклы

Но при этом не жёстко кодировать для данной ситуации, а написать универсальный поисковик, который будет в любой такой ситуации сразу находить то что нужно. При этом что бы он заранее структуру не знал, а проходился по любой структуре.

Синтаксис реализации может быть такой

```
FindInObject("id","1-1-1");
```

### 2. Через Regex

Сначала найти строку `"id": "1-1-1",` и ближайшее её окружение от `{` до `}`

Вот простейший Regex

```
"{[^{]*?\"id\": "1-1-1"[^}]*?}"

var var1 = "id";
var value = "\"1-1-1\"";
var regex = `{[^{]*?\"${var1}\": ${value}[^}]*?}`;
```

Конечно его можно доработать до более универсальной структуры и обрабатывать например дополнительные пробельные символы.

Вот тут тестируем - https://regex101.com/r/9yKlA6/1

Правда в вашем примере вы ещё и разные виды кавычек используете, при необходимости можно добавить в regex, но всё же лучше использовать один вид кавычек.